# Iterated Euler's totient function

Tags: number-theory, totient-function

Let $\phi(n)$ be the [Euler totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function): 
$$
\phi(2)=1 \;,\; \phi(11)=10 \;,\; \phi(12)=4\;,$$
etc.
Define $\Phi(n)$ to be the number of iterations $k$ so that $\phi^k(n)$
reaches $1$.
For example,
$\Phi(25)=5$ because $\phi(25)=20$ and continuing, it takes $5$ applications
to reach $1$:
$$25,20,8,4,2,1 \;.$$
Another example: $\Phi(113)=7$:
$$113,112,48,16,8,4,2,1 \;.$$
Here is a plot of $\Phi(n)$:

---

[image: Phi_n100]

          

<sup>Red curve: $0.43 + 1.22 \ln( n )$.</sup>

---

$\Phi(n)$ is fit quite well (and well beyond what's shown above) by $c \ln(n)$.

Two questions:

> ***Q1***. What explains the logarithmic growth, at a high-level?
>
> ***Q2***. What explains the constant $c \approx 1.22$?

Likely both of these questions are answered in the literature.

Comment: See whether this helps you: http://oeis.org/A003434

Comment: @Rohan: Thanks! Here's one fact from that OEIS entry: "Pillai proved that log(n/2)/log(3) + 1 <= a(n) <= log(n)/log(2) + 1," where a(n) is what I call $\Phi(n)$.

Comment: (@stefan4024: I would prefer the title not use LaTeX so it can be cited elsewhere.)

Comment: For the fun of it: [Iterated phi sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/149863), a coding challenge to output $\Phi(n)$ from $n=2$ to $n=100$.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke: What about making the title "Iterated φ(n) function" - i.e. using a φ symbol, but without LaTeX?

Comment: I don't think unicode phi symbol is better than "iterated phi(n) function". But n in the title is awkward. I think the best (most citable / searchable) is "iterated Euler totient function" or "Iterated phi function" or "Iterated Euler's phi function"

Comment: @6005: I take your suggestion; thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Note that $\phi(n)$ is even (for $n\ge3$), and if $n$ is even then $\phi(n)\le n/2$. This immediately gives you Pillai's logarithmic upper bound.

Comment: This is quite insightful, and certainly makes the $\alpha \log n$ conjecture that @lhf found plausible.

Answer (score 11):

Erdős et al. say this in [On the Normal Behavior of the Iterates Of some Arithmetic Functions](http://oeis.org/A000010/a000010_1.pdf):

> [...] it is easy to see that the set of numbers of the form $k(n)/ \log n$ is dense in $[1/ \log 3,1/ \log 2]$. What is still in doubt about $k(n)$ is its average and normal behavior. We conjecture that there is some constant $\alpha$ such that $k(n) \sim \alpha \log n$ on a set of asymptotic density $1$.

Here, $k(n)$ is what the OP calls $\Phi(n)$.

The [original paper](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4612-3464-7_13) was published in 1990. Perhaps it is still the state of the art.

Comment: The other authors of that paper are still around and active. Maybe one of them would know whether there has been any progress.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to show Pillai's lower bound. Here we use $ \varphi^*(n) $ to denote $ 
\Phi(n) $ because of the famous log-star function ($ \log^* $) in complexity.

To get started, we need a special variety of Euler's totient function $ \hat\varphi $, which is $\varphi$ without considering 2, namely $ \hat \varphi(x):=\begin{cases}\varphi(x), x\text{ odd}\\ 2\cdot\varphi(x), x\text{ even}\end{cases} $.

When $ k $ goes sufficiently large(actually it is just $ \varphi^*(x) $), it is easy to see that $ \varphi^k $ approaches $1$ and $ \hat\varphi^k $ approaches some power of $ 2$. Let's denote it as $2^{\sigma(x)} \le2^k=2^{\varphi^*(x)} $. The inequility is obvious. Then we make a claim.

**Claim.** For all odd number $ x $, there holds $ x\le 3^{\sigma(x)} $. The equality holds iff $ x $ is some power of $3$.

**Proof of the claim.** Obviously $ \sigma(2)=\sigma(3)=1, \sigma(3^k)=k $. And it is also easy to check that $ \sigma(pq)=\sigma(p)+\sigma(q) $. So we just need to deal with the prime numbers. By induction, we consider the prime $ p>3 $. We have known that $ p-1\le 3^{\sigma(p-1)}=:t $, and the equality never holds, so $ p-1<t $. Since $ \sigma(p-1)=\sigma(p) $ for prime $p$, and notice that $ p\neq 3^{\sigma(p)}=t $, from $ p-1<t,p\neq t $, we get $ p<t $.

Eventually the final step.

When $x $ is odd, $ \varphi^*(x)\ge\sigma(x)+1\ge\log_3n+1 $.

When $ x $ is even, we write $ x=2^d\cdot c, d\ge1, c\text{ odd} $, then $ \varphi^*(x)\ge \sigma(x)=d+\sigma(c)\ge d+\log_3c\ge1+ \log_3{x\over2}$. Easy to check the equality holds iff $ x =2\cdot3^k $ for some $ k $.

Here the proof ends.

The proof comes from a proof sketch by Deng Mingyang(moorhsum), the IMO 2019 gold medal winner from China, posted on [Zhihu(Chinese)](https://www.zhihu.com/question/267006361/answer/321060560), a chinese version of Quora. I prove the claim here which the sketch not contains. I am curious about why to construct such $ \hat\varphi $ and make such a claim.